# Why can't Nginx find Django's static files?

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to understand how static files are served up by Django using a project I've created on my Mac using Django 3, Gunicorn, and Nginx.  The website serves up templates correctly except that the templates can't see my CSS stylesheet.  When I go to a page, for example `127.0.0.1:8000/app1/` and view the source, I see this in my HTML template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
```

If I click on the href link, I get a page "Not Found" at the address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.css`.  This seems like it should be the correct link but the template can't see the main.css stylesheet as I would expect.

Here are the pertinent files in my 'mysite' project located in /Users/me/projects/django/django-staticfiles:

```
├── app1
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── app1
│   │       └── index.html
├── mysite
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── main.css
├── static-final
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── css
│       └── main.css
```

Here are the pertinent settings:

```
# mysite/settings.py
...
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', ]
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
]
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-final/')
...
```

I installed Gunicorn into my virtual environment and run it with this command:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 mysite.wsgi
```

I installed Nginx using Homebrew.  Here is the part of nginx.conf that includes my Nginx settings:

```
# /usr/local/etc/nginx.conf
...
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen      8080;
        server_name localhost;
    }
    ...
    include server/*;
}
```

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
# /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/django-staticfiles
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /Users/me/projects/django/django-staticfiles/static-final;
    }
}
```

I should add that when I stop Gunicorn and start Django's development server with DEBUG = True, the app1 template accesses the main.css file correctly.  It just can't see it when I'm running Gunicorn and Nginx.  I realize that I don't have a real need to run Gunicorn/Nginx on my Mac, but I've just set it up so I can compare and contrast how Django manages static files in development versus production.

Comment: You could try adding a trailing `/` to the `alias` value. The `location` and `alias` values should both have a trailing `/` or neither have a trailing `/` for the text substitution to work correctly.

Comment: Hi,

Nginx apply a priority following the order. If you want direct access to static, you must put `/static/` before `/` (who catch everything)